# Which adapter to get in order to use Dell U2515H with Thunderbolt port?

Tags: display, thunderbolt

I have MacBook Pro (late 2013) and I'm considering getting Dell U2515H QHD monitor. The MBP has two Thunderbolt ports.

The monitor supports DisplayPort and DisplayPort 1.2.

Which adapter I need to get in order to use the Dell U2515H with my MBP?

Comment: The thunderbolt is backwards compatible with displayport so a normal displayport cable works fine.

Comment: The MacBook Pro only has two Thunderbolt ports, not three.

Comment: @Hoshts So this would work ? http://www.amazon.de/Patuoxun-Thunderbolt-Displayport-Microsoft-Thinkpad/dp/B00MFO6A4O/ref=sr_1_17?ie=UTF8&qid=1453559173&sr=8-17-spons&keywords=thunderbolt+displayport&psc=1

Comment: @user3439894 True, my mistake.

Comment: @Chiron You should not need any adapter at all. The Dell U2515 comes with a dp-to-minidp cable.

Comment: Since the 2013 MacBook Pro has an HDMI port, why can't you just connect the monitor to it?

Comment: @Hoshts Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3439894 The HDMI can't output the same resolution as the displayport.

Comment: @user3439894 The monitor is QHD and afaik, HDMI will not handle that good.

Comment: @Hoshts Sure man :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MacBook Pro Thunderbolt ports are fully compatible with DisplayPort so as long as you have a DisplayPort cable, there is no need for an adapter.

I own 2x [Dell U2715H](http://accessories.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&sku=210-ADKB) myself. Dell is so nice to deliver their display with the needed cable. Working like a charm and I love the displays.

Comment: Which MacBook Pro do you have ? I have rMBP late 2013 and the U2515H is not working :( Constant black and white flickering and it is not working at all when pressing any key while the laptop is sleeping

Comment: Flickering? Sounds bad tbh. If it doesn't get a signal it should say that, like when cable is unplugged, but flickering?? Do the OSD work on the display? When the input select is showing, try hold the accept button for about 8 seconds. A modal should come up saying something about DisplayPort. Try enable/disable that (it is for DisplayPort 1.2 if I remember correctly)

Comment: Btw, did you use the mbp with an external display over DisplayPort earlier?

Comment: I didn't try my rMBP with any external monitor before. I'm having this exactly https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTIdH1KtJDk

Comment: It was very depressing. I returned the monitor. Looks like 13 inches late 2013 aren't supporting higher resolutions. 15 inches late 2013 do though !